# How to get Page Id from Confluence URL, or requests.get in Python? Want to set it as an object

Tags: python-3.x, confluence-rest-api

In Python, want to get the **Page ID** from a **Confluence URL/Title page** and use it for posting to that page further down in the code.  Already have the process working when I know the Page ID, but will need to destroy and create page every night with **Lambda**.

```py
import requests

checkPageExistsData = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers, auth=auth)
requestJson = checkPageExistsData.json()
pageId = ''
```

Want to be able to print or return `pageId`, basically want to get `pageId`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/rest/7.0.1/#api/content-getContent):

`http://example.com/confluence/rest/api/content?spaceKey=TST&title=Cheese`

You can then get the `id` from the response JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get what I needed from this:

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

url ="https://xxxxx.com"
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}
 auth=('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx')


def get_pageId():
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers, auth=auth)
    data = r.json()
    for results in data["results"]:
        id = (results["id"])
    return id

pageID = get_pageId()
print(pageID)
```